# Retrieving data from Firebase in Android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

My Database looks like this:

[image: Firebase Databse]

The code of my activity is this:

```
    public class FirebaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase);

        final List<String> glocations = new ArrayList<String>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                for (DataSnapshot child: children){
                    String data = child.getValue(String.class);
                    glocations.add(data);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,glocations);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Now whenever I try to open the activity from the settings menu on the main activity my application crashes. All I want it to do is show the Latitude, the longitude and the timestamps each time the user changes them in a listview by using a simple list with the array adapter.
This is a different activity and not the main one. The main one works perfectly. I've watched countless videos and I cannot understand my mistake.

The Error I get from logcat is this

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.thanoszoug.geofenceexample, PID: 9954
>                                                                                 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert
>   value of type java.util.HashMap to String
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaD(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.thanoszoug.geofenceexample.FirebaseActivity$1.onDataChange(FirebaseActivity.java:42)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: If your app crashes, logcat will contain a stack trace of the exception. Please add that to your question to improve your chances of getting help.

Comment: Done, thank for noting that out.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the exception is thrown at this line:

```
String data = child.getValue(String.class);
```

getValue will get you the node "Anonymous", and **all the rest of the data below it**, in a form of `HashMap`. Since you're trying to parse it to `String`, it throws you this error:

> Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

The reason for getting the node level of "Anonymous" is that you originally point your listener to "Users", and you run through its children by using a foreach loop, and each children's value is on the level of "Anonymous".

I advise you to reconsider the use of `String`, and in addition, if you wish to retrieve your locations data, you should reach it by `.child("Anonymous").child("Location").child("-KcU....")` in your own custom way of doing.

Comment: I kinda fixed this. My problem now is, I am using unique keys with .push() in the main activity but I wanna show the list of my database in another activity. is the a way to get through those keys by using the .child("Anonymous").child("Location").child("-KcU....")?